# PreRender event is not fired

Tags: asp.net, events, autowired

Recently i've noticed, that the Page_PreRender event is not being fired. If `protected override void OnPreRender` is used - everything is fine. AutoWire is enabled and the same code performs just fine on another machine...

Where should i dig?

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question.  Can you not use the protected override void OnPreRender syntax?

Comment: Do you mean not fired or your handler not handling it?

Comment: Can you post some code of the Page_PreRender method and also the page directive?

Comment: Matthew Jones: The issue is that it used to work and stopped on one isolated server. Still works fine on other machines

Adrian Godong: Basically if I put a breakpoint inside the method it never breaks there

Jeff Widmer: Everything is definitely fine there, because exact same page works on a different server.

Basically, does anyone know a global server setting that prevents AutoEventWireup from working?

Comment: A good question to start from. Where should I dig?

Comment: @ADC Wow, that's been so long ago. You should not even bother with WebForms these days. Better learn the ASP MVC framework.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I we got a site in our company based on ASP.NET pages and user controls.

Comment: I guess you're kinda stuck then :( Good luck.

Answer (score 13):

There are a few things that can cause it to not fire

- Visible property being set to false
- Response.End()

Comment: Visible property was my problem...not a terribly intuitive thing.

Comment: And here is the red cross to dig in!

Answer (score 7):

This is the event that should be overriden and used.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this and it appears you can set the AutoEventWireup in Web.Config and Machine.Config. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324151

So maybe the machine.config on that server has got something going on.

Might be worth looking at.

```
<configuration>    
<system.web>
<pages autoEventWireup="true|false" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```