# PreRender in ASP.NET Master Page not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, viewstate, autoeventwireup

Both `Page_PreRender` and `Page_Load` do not work in the Master Page I am working with. `Page_Init` does, however, for any reason. `AutoEventWireup` is set to true.

```
public partial class MyMaster : MasterPage
{
    public MyMaster()
    {
        // tried this too, but doesn't matter whether this LoC
        // is there or not
        this.PreRender += Page_PreRender;
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // does not fire
    }
}
```

I tried it out in an empty Web Project as well. There it works fine.

Edit: I figured out that setting `EnableViewState` to `true` fixes it:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="MyMaster.master.cs" Inherits="MyMaster" EnableViewState="false" %>
```

But I do not want the ViewState to be enabled. Overriding `OnPreRender` works as well, no matter what value `EnableViewState` has. Now I'm wondering why, and just using the override way seems a hacky to me. Can anybody help?

Comment: why do you expect that the method Pool will be called at all inside the class myMaster?

Comment: Sorry, this is the constructor. Copy+paste-fail while copying code from several windows into the post.

Comment: do you call a page which references to your master page?

Comment: I do. This works great so far, including ASP.NET correctly wiring and invoking `Page_Init`.

Comment: @Mudu - You have to post markup and code-behind of "said" master page. Read this thread too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168189/prerender-event-is-not-fired

Comment: AVD, I updated the question with more information. I think I could narrow down the significant markup to this single line. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use `AutoEventWireup` in the page directive, so would you please try as below:

In your page directive  `<%@ Page ...`, use `AutoEventWireup="true"` and in your master page, remove `PreRender` event subscription:

```
public MyMaster()
{
    // tried this too, but doesn't matter whether this LoC
    // is there or not
    //this.PreRender += Page_PreRender;
}
```

Hope everything is fine now, thanks for your time.

**Edit:** Please check in your `web.config` file and ensure that `AutoEventWireup` is not set to `False`.

Comment: Thanks to you Elias. Unfortunately is isn't yet. I double-checked my code, and everything is like you suggested.

Comment: This is totally nonsense @Mudu, you should try first and should let me know, thanks for your time.

Comment: We must have misunderstood each other. I did indeed try what you wrote, but it is not working. Besides, I did not vote down your answer, in case you feel offended.

Comment: Oh, sorry for blaming you, however I'm sure the voter did it intentionally without testing or without reading.